# understaning assembly code in windbg

Tags: assembly, windbg

I was debugging some code in windbg and I am not able to understand some assembly code

```
78151113 ff1230401e78    call    dword ptr [Somefunction (781e9950)] ds:0023:781e9950=028d1170
```

Can someone explain what this statement means.I know this is call statement but how it is jumping to 028d1170 address

Comment: Second that.  Start, for instance, with the first google entry, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language, and work from there.

Comment: @Bombe, He's gotta start somewhere - but this isn't the right way/place to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This address call a function pointer. The function pointer is stored at address 781e9950. If you check the contents of the address 781e9950, you will find it has the value 028d1170.